# Error: Expected ';' , ',' or ')' before (first argument's name)

Tags: c

I am new to C and have a problem with my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool a(char[], int);
void b(char[], int[], int);
void c(char[], int[], int, int);
void d(char[], int, int[], int);


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
return 0;
}

bool a(char[] x, int y) {
return true;
}
void b(char[] x, int[] y, int z) {
}
void c(char[] x, int[] y, int z, int q) {
}
void d(char[] x, int y, int[] z, int q) {
}
```

This code doesn't compile, but gives me an error message instead.

The problem is, I don't see why it does that...

Comment: Next time, post full error message in the question, not only part of it in the title. For now, try adding `;` after `}` for empty functions.

Comment: I ran the posted code through my gcc compiler, with all the warnings enabled. There were a HUGE number of errors/warnings.  for example. 'this line: 'bool a(char[] x, int y) {' (after placing the [] in the right places) should be: 'bool a(char x[], int y) {'  or event better: 'bool a(char* x, int y) {' the same considerations need to be applied to almost every line in the code.  Then, a warning message for each passed parameter that is not actually used

Comment: If you were to read the error and warning messages from the compiler, it would clearly tell you just what is wrong with the syntax of the code.  (You are compiling with all warnings enabled?)  When all the syntax problems are fixed, then you can continue.

Comment: placing matching braces vertically and a blank line or two between functions would make your code much easier to read/debug.  Remember, the idea is NOT to use the minimum number of lines nor to make the source file as small as possible, but rather to make it easy for a human (thats' you and me) to read/understand the code

Comment: Curiosity: Did you created a 'bool' struct? C does not have bool as a primitive type

Comment: @felipeek: *that* the OP got right: `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: @Jongware true, I didn't see that include. Well observed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool a(char[] x, int y) {
```

must be

```
bool a(char x[], int y) {
```

(And so on for the other definitions.)

Comment: Oh damn, I keep forgetting this isn't Java :(